# Is it possible to overwrite javaScript primitive data type?

Tags: javascript

Question is self explanatory. I know it is possible to extend primitive data types such as `string` but is it possible to overwrite it?

This is a question that has been asked in an interview.

Comment: Overwrite what exactly?

Comment: eg. String, lets say string should always have one number.

Comment: It used to be possible to overwrite the Array constructor for instance, but has been fixed because of JSON-linked security holes, see there : http://ejohn.org/blog/re-securing-json/ - says it's not possible to overwrite global objects' constructors anymore, at least in FF (suppose it's the case in all major browsers by now).

Comment: What do you mean by "have one number"? That `"somestring" + 5 === 6`?

Comment: I mean "this is not a valid string" but "this is 1" because it contains an int.

Comment: Primitive datatypes are not extensible at all. If you mean extending `String.prototype` for example, then you are extending String *objects*, not primitive strings. That said, you can write your own JavaScript engine and do whatever you want!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot overwrite anything. EcmaScript [defines the primitive types](http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.2) `Undefined`, `Null`, `Boolean`, `Number`, and `String`; these are internal and will be used regardless of what you are doing (for example overwriting the global `String` constructor). [Type conversion](http://es5.github.com/#x9) and evaluation of literals does not rely on any public functions but uses only these internal types and the algorithms specified for them.

Of course, if someone does string coercion with `String(myval)` instead of `""+myval` assigning to the global `String` variable will have an effect on that code. Any internal use would still point to the "old" function.

---

If you were talking about prototype objects for the primitive types (when used [as objects](http://es5.github.com/#x9.9)), those are not overwritable as well. You may extend those objects, but as soon as you assign to e.g. `Number.prototype` you just have lost a reference to the actual, original number protype object. Example spec for [The Number constructor](http://es5.github.com/#x15.7.2):

> The [prototype] of the newly constructed object is set to the **original** Number prototype object, the one that is the **initial value** of `Number.prototype` ([15.7.3.1](http://es5.github.com/#x15.7.3.1))

Answer (score 1):

Yes (*edit: almost*). Open up a Javascript console (F12 if you're using Chrome) and type

```
String = function(){alert('bang!')};
```

You can overwrite (*edit: almost*) everything in Javascript — even the `window` global context! [evil.js](https://github.com/kitcambridge/evil.js) is a library that uses this trick to rewrite many native objects as possible.

Needless to say, this is extremely dangerous. I performed the `String` remapping code above, and since writing it down I've caused over 520 Javascript errors (and I've seen 'bang' alerted quite a few times). Native objects are used everywhere, and you shouldn't modify these in case 3rd party code relies on them in ways you don't know about. This is one of the reasons Prototype.js lost popularity — because its extension of native objects would often work against the expectations of other code.

**Edit:** Factually incorrect assertion that absolutely everything could be overwritten, as pointed out in [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15136413/356541). Edits made inline.

Comment: There are also reserved keywords that are impossible to overwrite (for, yield...). And for me, window can actually not be overwritten using Firebug on FF (though it isn't apparent at first).

Answer (score 1):

1. You can extend prototypes of native types.

   ```
   String.prototype.moo = function() { 
      console.log( 'Moo!' ) 
   };
   'Cow says'.moo();
   >> "Moo!"
   ```
2. However you cannot directly overwrite constructors of built-in types unless you overwrite the reference to the entire object:

   ```
   String = function() { 
      console.log( 'Custom function.' ) 
   };

   new String( 'Hello!' );
   >> "Custom function."
   >> String {} // now you've broken your website ;)
   ```
3. ...but still:

   ```
   'Wat?!'
   >> "Wat?!" // you can still create strings by typing letters in quotes
   ```

So... the answer is "yes but no". You can mess with native types (`Number`, `Date`, `String`...) but you cannot re-define them entirely from scratch. They're a part of JS engine that you're using (most likely native C++ code) and this brings some limitations.

Comment: Note that `X.prototype.constructor` is actually not used internally, for any type (custom or built-in), so changing it will never have any effect. It's just a convient reference to the constructor for the user.

Comment: To fix the broken website, do `String = "".constructor` :-)

Comment: @Bergi Yessss. But by broking the website I meant that methods like `charAt` or `slice` are no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

Possible like this but you must always succeed without side effects.Not good practice.

```
function Array() {
  var obj = this;
  var ind = 0;
  var getNext = function(x) {
    obj[ind++] setter = getNext;
    if (x) alert("Data stolen from array: " + x.toString());
  };
  this[ind++] setter = getNext;
}
var a = ["private stuff"];
// alert("Data stolen from array: private stuff");
```

Comment: a) this was a bug in old browser; array literals do not invoke a global `Array` function b) the OP asked about *primitive*  types.