# If we can override undefined in Javascript, where does 'void 0' takes value from?

Tags: javascript

I know that `undefined` isn't reserved keyword and one can make whatever he wants with it. So we can override it for example. But if we override `undefined` in Javascript, where does `void 0` takes value from?

Try this piece of code:

```
let undefined = 'test';
console.log(undefined); // prints out 'test'
console.log(void 0); // prints out 'undefined'
```

At the first glance, it looks, that Javascript provides second version of `undefined` somewhere inside and returns it always as a result of `void` operator.

Comment: `let undefined = 'test'` isn't valid syntax

Comment: If something evaluates to undefined then the engine will return its implementation of the primitive type known as undefined. For it to return 'test' assumes its returning an accessible global with that name, which is not the case.

Comment: It is syntactically correct. Semantically though, `let` will throw an error because `undefined` is already defined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`void 0` isn't pulling its value from your `undefined` variable. It's returning the primitive type `undefined`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive.

Your code is defining a variable by the same name -- not redefining the primitive type itself. To my knowledge, that can't be done.

See more on this question: [Is it possible to overwrite javaScript primitive data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136148/is-it-possible-to-overwrite-javascript-primitive-data-type)

Comment: This is my answer :)

Comment: As a quick follow-up, try this as a test:  `console.log(typeof undefined); var undefined = "test"; console.log(typeof undefined); console.log(typeof undefinedVariable);`

Comment: @SeanKendle - well, your test doesn't prove anything. Can you explain what you had in mind?

Comment: That `undefined` is both a variable TYPE and a variable.  If you alter the variable, you're not altering the variable type.  It's the same as saying `var newString = "test"; var string = "a value"; console.log(typeof newString);`

That last log doesn't print out "a value" it prints out "string".

Comment: My original test proves that the variable type `undefined` is not being changed by the second line.

Answer (score 0):

*undefined* points to an internal object. *void* returns that internal object.

Answer (score 0):

[void operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) always returns `undefined` for any `operator` passed. This `undefined` returned by `void` [represents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) the primitive value `undefined` which is **NOT** writable, enumerable and configurable.

From your code,

```
   let undefined = 'test';
```

If you [check](https://jsfiddle.net/1zuncn1j/) the type, you will get `string`.

```
console.log(typeof(undefined))  //returns string
```

This means the `undefined` initialized as variable is not the primitive `undefined` which `void expression` returns.